# String conversion returns null

Tags: python

Trying to convert this string (put in the variable `a1`):

```
 '\'redis_import\':\'start\',\'redis_import\':\'dim_user_level\''
```

to:

```
'\'start\':\'redis_import\',\'dim_user_level\':\'redis_import\''
```

I have tried `print a1.split(',').reverse()` but this returns `null`. Why? and how to achieve this without using a loop?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's not a valid python string, please fix it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sorry I forgot to edit it. Now the string is fine.

Comment: So you want to parse it as dict and revert the key-value pairs?

Comment: @LutzHorn exactly. I want to use `eval(a1)` to parse it as dict. But before that this converse should be finished since it has same keys..

Comment: So, something like `','.join([':'.join(i.split(':')[::-1]) for i in  string.split(',')])`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for you reply! It looks cool. But the structure is too complicated for me to understand at the moment. Can you please tell me the name of this kind of expressions so that I can read more materials.

Comment: There's lot going on there. I use str split to split your string into chunks, and then split each chunk into keys and values, reverse them, join them, and then join the reversed chunks. This is done using split, join, and a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on comma, split on colons, reverse, join colons, join commas:

```
s = '\'redis_import\':\'start\',\'redis_import\':\'dim_user_level\''
','.join(':'.join(i.split(':')[::-1]) for i in s.split(','))
#"'start':'redis_import','dim_user_level':'redis_import'"
```

To understand this better just observe the output of these different calls:

```
>>> s.split(',')
["'redis_import':'start'", "'redis_import':'dim_user_level'"]
>>> s.split(',')[0]
"'redis_import':'start'"
>>> s.split(',')[0].split(':')
["'redis_import'", "'start'"]
>>> s.split(',')[0].split(':')[::-1]
["'start'", "'redis_import'"]
>>> ','.join(('a', 'b', 'c'))
'a,b,c'
>>> [i[::-1] for i in [[1,2], [3,4]]]
[[2, 1], [4, 3]]
```

---

Some further reading:

- [`str.split` - the method used to separate the strings at delimiters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [`str.join` - the method used to join iterables back to strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [a good introduction to those one-line generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)
- [a section about slicing and how they can be used to reverse sequences](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

Answer (score 2):

First of all `.reverse()` method reverse the list and returns `None`

so you can use [reversed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) which will return you iterator of reverse of the list

```
a =  '\'redis_import\':\'start\',\'redis_import\':\'dim_user_level\''

print(', '.join([':'.join(reversed(i.split(':'))) for i in a.split(',')])) # "'start':'redis_import', 'dim_user_level':'redis_import'"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it as a dict.

```
s = '\'redis_import\':\'start\',\'redis_import\':\'dim_user_level\''
res = {}
for i in s.split(","):
    val =  list(reversed(i.split(":")))
    res[val[0].replace("'", "")] = val[1].replace("'", "")    
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'start': 'redis_import', 'dim_user_level': 'redis_import'}
```